# Overriding log4j2's date class

Tags: date, logging, live, simulation, log4j2

I am writing a code which I can run in live or historical simulation mode. I am using log4j2 for logging and am printing the date and time as part of each log message. The works very well when I am running the code in live mode; however, when I am running the code in historical simulation mode I would like to get the historical date and time in the log messages instead of the actual wall-clock date and time. What is the best approach to changing the date behavior in log4j2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better way to do this, but I managed to change the date class used in log4j2 using log4j2's Asynchronous Loggers and a custom clock class:

First write a class that implements log4j2's clock class [1](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/log4j2/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/helpers/Clock.java), say org.my.date. 
Next, run the code passing the following to the jvm:

```
-DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector          -Dlog4j.Clock=org.my.date
```